# C# LINQ - Filtering by list-type property within a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class objects where one of the class properties is a `List<string>` containing miscellaneous values. I need to write a LINQ query to return the class objects containing a certain value within the `List<string>` property.

Here's an example class...

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

And here's an example of some data and a method that filters based on a specified attribute value:

```
public class Info
{
    public List<Item> GetItemInfo(string Attribute = null)
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Name = "Wrench",  ID = 0, Attributes = new List<string> { "Tool"  } },
            new Item { Name = "Pear",    ID = 1, Attributes = new List<string> { "Fruit" } },
            new Item { Name = "Apple",   ID = 2, Attributes = new List<string> { "Fruit" } },
            new Item { Name = "Drill",   ID = 3, Attributes = new List<string> { "Tool",   "Power"  } },
            new Item { Name = "Bear",    ID = 4, Attributes = new List<string> { "Animal", "Mammal" } },
            new Item { Name = "Shark",   ID = 5, Attributes = new List<string> { "Animal", "Fish"   } }
        };

        // If no Attribute specified, return the entire item list
        if (Attribute == null) return itemList;

        // Otherwise, filter by the Attribute specified
        else return  ?????
    }
}
```

A call to the `GetItemInfo` method would return this:

`myInfo.GetItemInfo("Tool")` should return the Items with names "Wrench" and "Drill"

`myInfo.GetItemInfo("Power")` should return only the Item with name "Drill"

`myInfo.GetItemInfo("Fruit")` should return the Items with names "Pear" and "Apple"

Easy enough to write a LINQ expression with a sub-query. In this case, however, because the `List<string>` has no column name to reference, I'm struggling with how to write this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Otherwise, filter by the Attribute specified
else return itemList
    .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains(Attribute))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Linq `Where` clause along with the `Any` extension method.

```
...
...
if (Attribute == null) return itemList;    
return itemList.Where(item => item.Attributes.Any(x => x == Attribute)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a LINQ Where clause?

```
public class Info
{
    public List<Item> GetItemInfo(string Attribute = null)
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Name = "Wrench",  ID = 0, Attributes = new List<string> { "Tool"  } },
            new Item { Name = "Pear",    ID = 1, Attributes = new List<string> { "Fruit" } },
            new Item { Name = "Apple",   ID = 2, Attributes = new List<string> { "Fruit" } },
            new Item { Name = "Drill",   ID = 3, Attributes = new List<string> { "Tool",   "Power"  } },
            new Item { Name = "Bear",    ID = 4, Attributes = new List<string> { "Animal", "Mammal" } },
            new Item { Name = "Shark",   ID = 5, Attributes = new List<string> { "Animal", "Fish"   } }
        };

        // If no Attribute specified, return the entire item list
        if (Attribute == null) return itemList;

        // Otherwise, filter by the Attribute specified
        else return itemList.Where(i => i.Attributes.Contains(Attribute)).ToList();
    }
}
```